# Remove or merge multidimensionals arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to from array like this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SKU] => T
                        [title] => BT
                        [min] => SPads
                    )

                [1] =>
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SKU] => R
                        [title] => RT
                        [min] => XPads
                    )

                [1] =>
            )
    )
```

make arrays like this:

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SKU] => T
                        [title] => BT
                        [min] => SPads
                    )

                [1] =>
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SKU] => R
                        [title] => RT
                        [min] => XPads
                    )

                [1] =>
            )
```

And how to array like this

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SKU] => T
                        [title] => BT
                        [min] => SPads
                    )

                [1] =>
            )

    )
```

make array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (

                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [SKU] => T
                        [title] => BT
                        [min] => SPads
                    )

                [1] =>

    )
```

I only found soultions with removing multidimensionals arrays using value, but here im not having value, im having just key, any help?

array_splice and array_diff is php functions that i using to solve my problem from this website https://www.php.net but i didnt found the solution.

Comment: I think [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Try `$newArray = array_values($oldArray);`

Comment: _"but here im not having value, im having just key"_ - All your keys have a value. A multidimensional array is just an array where the values are other arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing first index can be achieve by using array_shift, see demo below.

```
<?php
//Enter your code here, enjoy!
$a = [
    0 => [
        0 => [
            0 => [
                'SKU'   => 'T',
                'title' => 'BT',
                'min'   => 'SPads',
            ],
            1 => '',
        ],
        [
            0 => [
                'SKU'   => 'R',
                'title' => 'RT',
                'min'   => 'XPads',
            ],
            1 => '',
        ],
    ],
];
$a = array_shift($a);
print_r($a);
```

[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) - Shift an element off the beginning of array

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SKU] => T
                    [title] => BT
                    [min] => SPads
                )

            [1] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [SKU] => R
                    [title] => RT
                    [min] => XPads
                )

            [1] => 
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b1497c13d95d0d23621fc39f061cd3b26f8d4ca).

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate in foreach loop and create new array in reqired formate.

```
$newAr =array();

foreach ($oldArr as $tempArr){
 foreach($tempArr as $tempArr2){
   $newAr[] = $tempArr2;
 }
}

print_r($newArr);
```